# Shopify Graphql API - draftOrderCreate redirect to Checkout with Discount Code Field

Tags: graphql, shopify, shopify-api

If you are familiar with Shopify draftOrderCreate API, you know that when retrieving the invoice_url via the graphql mutation, it will redirect you to the checkout page but there will be no DISCOUNT CODE Field, and Shopify docs are clear with this, but upon checking some apps (https://apps.shopify.com/draft-helper) it is possible, but on the said app, you will manually generate the checkout link.

Here's a photo of what that app is doing
[image]

I am wondering how do i integrate this automatically via graphql. When checking the Console (Network) it seems like he is only passing the draft order id as payload.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a Draft Order, you can provide a discount. So if you do that, and then send the invoice, the discount should be applied correctly.

Comment: Hey Mr. David Lazar, Thanks for a quick reply, yes I can actually do that using applied_discount, but what i need is to have the Discount Code field show and customer can either add, edit, or even delete their own discount.

Comment: Well. Have fun with that then.